# Python: Can't fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' "

Tags: python, cmd, module, scikit-learn, pip

I already installed `sklearn` through `pip install scikit-learn` but I still get this message when I try to run it

[image: this message when I try to run it]

I already tried a bunch of stuff to fix it. But nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: make sure you are using `pip3` instead of `pip2`.

Comment: @ltd9938 I think the problem might be the other way round. (i.e. installing python3 libraries, but trying to run via python2)

Comment: I'm currently using Python 3.6.2 what would be the correct way to run it? I'm using cmd.

Answer (score 0):

As @TasosPapastylianou said, your current `pip` defaults to `pip3` and installs `scikit-learn` to python3 libraries.

You need to check which version of python is your `iris.py` using. (It should be available in the top lines of that file). Most probably it is using only `python`.
Something like this:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

You can check which version the `python` command is using by doing:

```
python -V
```

Most probably it will default to `python2` and not `python3`.

There are multiple ways to solve this:

1. Try `python3 iris.py` to execute the script.
2. Change the shebang in the top line of the file to:

   `#!/usr/bin/env python3`